# Adjust Time & Date settings via teminal

Tags: command-line, 14.04, time, date

How do I adjust the Time & Date manually via terminal (CLI) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this manually via the `time` and `date` commands.

source and further details `man time` and `man date`